# by() error in r: could not find function "FUN"

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to apply a t-test to a factor with 24 levels (speaker). My goal is to see if there is a significant difference between orthography (2 levels: jj or L) according to the continuous variable, intensity difference (intdiff). However, when using the by() function, it returned the following error:

```
Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : could not find function "FUN"
```

My syntax which produced the error was:

```
 by(data, data$speaker, t.test(intdiff~orthography))
```

I specified the arguments according to the R documentation, so I can't figure out why it's not accepting the function I provided. Any help would be greatly appreciated. In the event you need to try to reproduce the problem, here is the data set with which I am working:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/bxb9ebavln1rh3u/SpanishPalatals.csv

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `by` is looking for a function name, not a complete function, like `by(data, factor, mean)`.

Comment: I'm not planning to download a 300+KB file. You should use small files for testing and post dput() for such examples.

Comment: There is only one `orthography` level for `speaker` `f22s`.

Comment: @DWin Sorry! I thought that was a pretty small size for a file. I will keep that in mind for future posts. Thanks.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein Yes. I just saw that. That's not hard to fix though. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This: `t.test(intdiff~orthography)` is not a function. It appears you are expecting `by` to split a dataframe so this might succeed:

```
by(data, data$speaker, function(d){ t.test(d$intdiff ~ d$orthography, data=d)} )
```

To explain further: `function(d){ t.test(d$intdiff ~ d$orthography)}` is a function. Or you could try:

```
by(data, data$speaker,  t.test, form= intdiff ~ orthography ) # untested
```

The second version uses t.test (which is a function 'name' rather than a function 'call') and there is a formula method for t.test. The matching with argument names accepts partial names, so the dataframe being passed to`` `.test `` should get automatically matched to the 'data' argument.

Comment: Thank you. That solves my problem and I learned something new. :)

Comment: The convention with `apply` and `by` is that the unnamed object being passed to a target function "sticks" (gets matched to) to the first otherwise unmatched parameter. They have a "dots" parameter that carries "further parameters" that get matched by name. The help page Usage section of the target is essential reading to use apply/by/tapply "functionals" properly. Hadley Wickham has a useful "Functionals" section of his draft text on this programming paradigm.

Answer (score 1):

The following:

```
ff <- function(spkr){
  tt <- t.test(intdiff~orthography,data=df[df$speaker==spkr,])
  p  <- tt$p.value
  return (c(as.character(spkr), p,
            ifelse(p<0.01,"***",ifelse(p<0.05,"**",ifelse(p<0.1,"*","")))))
}

result <- sapply(unique(df$speaker),ff)
result <- data.frame(t(result))
colnames(result) <- c("speaker","p","")
```

Produces this with your dataset:

```
> result
   speaker                   p    
1     f11r   0.274156477338993    
2     f13r   0.713051221315941    
3     f15a   0.572200487250118    
4     f16a   0.192474372524439    
5     f19s   0.071456754899202   *
6     f21s   0.172336984420981    
7     f23s 0.00711798616059324 ***
8     f24s   0.875438396151962    
9     f31s  0.0191665818354575  **
10    f35s   0.550666959777641    
11    f36s   0.715870353562376    
12    m09a   0.195488505334365    
13    m10a  0.0083410071012031 ***
14    m12r   0.461148808729932    
15    m14r   0.407116475315898    
16    m17s 0.00147426201434577 ***
17    m18s   0.614243811131762    
18    m20s   0.204627912633947    
19    m25s 0.00652026971231048 ***
20    m26s   0.135705391035981    
21    m27s   0.099118573524907   *
22    m28s  0.0789796806312655   *
23    m32s    0.27026239413494
```

Note that one of the speakers had only 1 orthography (speaker = f22s), which causes the t.test to fail, so I removed it.