# Performing function on chunks of data in R

Tags: r, function, testing, p-value

I have data that looks like this

```
    is_severe     encoding    sn_id
1           1        1   chr1 14907
2           1        1   chr1 14930
3           1        1   chr1 15211
4           1        2   chr1 15274
5           1        1   chr1 16378
6           1        1   chr1 16495
7           1        1   chr1 16534
8           1        1   chr1 17689
9           1        2   chr1 69511
10          1        2   chr1 69511
11          1        1   chr1 69511
12          0        1   chr1 69511
```

What I need to do is to perform Cochran-Armitage which is done by the catt function (link with explanations about the function https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/CATT/html/CATT.html).
For every unique sn_id I want to perform it this is the code for the function:

```
CATT(data$is_severe,data$encoding)
```

To do it on every "chunk" of data of the unique sn_id column I did:

```
by(df,df$sn_id,CATT(df$is_severe,df$encoding))
```

but got the error message:

```
could not find function "FUN"
```

I found this post-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20316778/by-error-in-r-could-not-find-function-fun
and my intentions are similar to get the pvalue of the test for every unique "chunk" of data of sn_id column.
For example chunk of data it has the same value in sn_id column - chr1 69511 and for those 4 observation I want to use catt function (there are a lot of different chunks like this in the data so i would like to preform the test on each one of them and get the pvalue):

```
9           1        2   chr1 69511
10          1        2   chr1 69511
11          1        1   chr1 69511
12          0        1   chr1 69511
```

This is the dput of my data:

```
structure(list(X = 0:4, CHROM = c("chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", 
"chr1"), POS = c("14907", "14930", "15211", "15274", "16378"), 
    REF = c("A", "A", "T", "A", "T"), ALT = c("G", "G", "G", 
    "T", "C"), AF_VALUE = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0.5), hetro.homo = c("hetro", 
    "hetro", "hetro", "homo", "hetro"), id_ = c("i_peb107_270", 
    "i_peb107_270", "i_peb107_270", "i_peb107_270", "i_peb107_270"
    ), Phenotype = c("Severe", "Severe", "Severe", "Severe", 
    "Severe"), is_severe = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), encoding = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), sn_id = c("chr1 14907", "chr1 14930", "chr1 15211", 
    "chr1 15274", "chr1 16378")), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Unfortunately, this solution didn't work.
Instead, I tried to use the catt function from an archived package in R  - HapEstXXR (https://rdrr.io/cran/HapEstXXR/man/catt.html):

```
catt <-
  function(y, x, score = c(0, 1, 2)) {
    miss <- unique(c(which(is.na(y)), which(is.na(x))))
    n.miss <- length(miss)
    if(n.miss > 0) {
      y <- y[-miss]
      x <- x[-miss]
    }
    if(!all((y == 0) | (y == 1))) 
      stop("y should be only 0 or 1.")
    if(!all((x == 0) | (x == 1) |(x == 2))) 
      stop("x should be only 0, 1 or 2.")
    ca <- x [y == 1]
    co <- x [y == 0]
    htca <- table(ca)
    htco <- table(co)
    A <- matrix(0, 2, 3)
    colnames(A) <- c(0, 1, 2)
    rownames(A) <- c(0, 1)
    A[1, names(htca)] <- htca
    A[2, names(htco)] <- htco
    ptt <- prop.trend.test(A[1, ], colSums(A), score = score)
    res <- list("2x3-table" = A, 
                chisq = as.numeric(ptt$statistic), 
                df = as.numeric(ptt$parameter), 
                p.value = as.numeric(ptt$p.value), 
                n.miss = n.miss)
    return(res)
```

I tried it on some data take I just wrote by myself:

```
ï.       is_severe encoding
1            1        1
2            1        1
3            1        1
4            1        2
5            0        2
6            0        2
7            0        1
```

and it worked great:

[image]

The problem is when I try to apply it to part of data as mentioned above, is there any way to fix this?

Comment: please share your data with `dput(df)` so that we can use it. what do you mean by chunk of data? `chunks` has a specific meaning in rmarkdown so it might be better to find a different way to describe your data

Comment: The easiest way to include data samples as text (and code that captures the data structure) is to run `dput(head(MY_DATA))`

Comment: @ Jon Spring edited..

Comment: @Mike edited with new results

Comment: @JonSpring edited with new results

Answer (score 0):

```
by(df,df$sn_id, function(df) CATT(df$is_severe,df$encoding))
```

Comment: it returned an error :Error in `[.default`(tbl, 2, ) : subscript out of bounds

Comment: Can you supply dput(df) in your original post?

Comment: - i am trying my data is just very large over 150MB and it makes my R crush when i do this

Comment: `dput(head(MY_DATA, HOW_MANY_ROWS_TO_INCLUDE))`

Comment: It appears to be a problem specific to you data since the error is in CATT. 
Also forcing the example adding a leading 0: by(df,df$sn_id, function(df) CATT(c(0,df$is_severe), c(0,df$encoding)))  works to me

Comment: @RicardoVillalba gives error :Error in `[.default`(tbl, 2, ) : subscript out of bounds

Comment: @RicardoVillalba edited with new results